# Sorting Wins and Losses

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a data set that looks like:

[image]

I want to scan the row of numbers for say `5`s then check the cell above it for a `W` and if it is a `W` add one to the cell.

I would have a separate cell for counting each of `W`s and `L`s so I would modify the formula accordingly. For the above example the answer for the `5`s would be `2` W's and `0` L's.

What would the formula for that be?

Comment: I would have a separate cell for W's and L's so I would modify the formula accordingly. So for the above example the answer for the 5s would be two W's and no L's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say your data set is found on `A1:K2`
[image]

And on A4 you will enter the lookup number.

So you will enter on 2 other cells:

For Ws:

```
=COUNT(IF(A1:K1="W",IF(A2:K2=$A$4,A2:K2,"")))
```

For Ls:

```
=COUNT(IF(A1:K1="L",IF(A2:K2=$A$4,A2:K2,"")))
```

I made to IFs for the desired number and for the letter and after that asimple count.
Note that this is an array formula so you need to enter `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER` when entering the formula.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly!

Comment: Did it! Thanks. If I wanted to have two look up numbers in one cell or if that's not possible two cells each with their own look up number how would I do that?

Comment: This will do it for both of them again with array command: =COUNT(IF(A1:K1="W",IF(A2:K2=$A$4,A2:K2,"")))&"W "&COUNT(IF(A1:K1="L",IF(A2:K2=$A$4,A2:K2,"")))&"L"

Comment: Sorry I mean like A4 was the look up number which we were using 5 let's say I wanted 5 and 9 to be done together. Could I put them in the same lookup cell a certain way or could I add a second lookup cell to the formula for the 9?

Comment: Place your 2nd number on b4 and then take this formulas:=COUNT(IF(A1:K1="L",IF(A2:K2=$A$4,A2:K2,"")))+COUNT(IF(A1:K1="L",IF(A2:K2=$B$4,A2:K2,"")))                                                                                        =COUNT(IF(A1:K1="W",IF(A2:K2=$A$4,A2:K2,"")))+COUNT(IF(A1:K1="W",IF(A2:K2=$B$4,A2:K2,"")))

Comment: Ahh thank you I should of been able to figure that out. But thanks again for all of your help. Much appreciated!